# I have downloaded the latest version of Gradle 7.3 that I would like to use in my Visual studio project EXPO

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, visual-studio, gradle

### I double checked to see if I have it installed..

### Gradle 7.3

so that's fine.. the problem comes when I enter the command gradle --daemon

**I get this error**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'RentInCars'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2/gradle-7.2.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2/gradle-7.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2/gradle-7.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

I tried using sudo gradle --daemon.. still gives me the same error..
what should I try next?

Comment: Go to your browser , and check if [this link](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2/gradle-7.2.pom) is available , if not you will need to use VPN and set up with gradle properly .

Comment: I went to the link and it is not available.. Can I know why do I need to use VPN to set up with gradle properly ?

Comment: Its probably because of where you live , google is like so many other services are banned from serving my area . so you need a VPN to connect .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in comments , you ll need VPN but not any VPN .

You have to know what port your vpn is working on .

for example , if you downloaded psiphone , you can go to settings , then local proxy ports and you can add 12345 as port for example .

then you need to go to .gradle folder , if your using windows its usually located at USER/%USERNAME%/.gradle , and create a global gradle.properties and then add the following .

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=12345
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=12345
```

This will redirect all gradle connection throw your proxy , in the case psiphone for example.

Comment: thank you for replying.. I am using Mac to create a react native application using expo.. which one should I download though? sorry for being ignorant .
Psiphon Pro for Android in the Google Play Store
Psiphon for iOS in the Apple App Store
Psiphon for Macs with Apple silicon in the Apple App Store (my Mac is 2019 version)
Psiphon Browser for iOS in the Apple App Store
Psiphon for Android direct download

Comment: i think [this one](https://apps.apple.com/app/psiphon/id1276263909) is the one your looking for if your using mac . and please consider up voting if the answer helped , and mark as accepted if the answer solved your problem .

Comment: as soon as I solve this issue. I'm definitely vote up

Comment: psiphone is not compatible with my Mac :( .. any other VPN you can suggest?

Comment: any VPN , that you can know its port will work , am using a paid proxy not a free one with user name and password , even this will work if you can have one .

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried this and have faced the same issue.
I later find [Gradle 7.3 is not added here yet](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle-api?repo=google)

Comment: try Gradle 7.0.3